# my jQuery script isn't working...but I'm not sure why

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

first off I know this can be achieved purely with CSS but I have recently learned jQuery and though I would have a crack at doing it via jQuery instead to help in improve my skills.

I am trying to make it so when I mouse over an image it goes to half opacity... I know it should be simple. but I think I must be missing something
my markup is `<img class="port-item-img" src="...">`
and my script is

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".port-item-img").hover(function() {
                $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
            };
        );
    });
```

any reason this shouldn't work?

Comment: Is there an error in the Javascript console?

Comment: typo `};` the `;` should not be there - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m974edo0/1/

Comment: though the hover implementation should be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m974edo0/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".port-item-img").hover(function() {
            $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
        });
 });
```

you added `;` for `}`

Answer (score 0):

You had an extra semi-colon. Remove that and make sure you include jQuery and an image that has a proper url.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".port-item-img").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
    }); //<--- Here was an extra ; 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9qhmt21k/)

Comment: thanks for pointing out the extra ; ... but still not working. the img is wrapped in a <ahref> which is in a <li> that shouldnt make a difference should it?

Comment: can you make a fiddle @ShoutItWebSolutions?

Comment: it works fine in the fiddle im using wordpress and calling the bloginfo('template_directory'); function to echo out the url ... that wouldn't be affecting it would it?

Comment: @ShoutItWebSolutions it is working fine in http://jsfiddle.net/2u2L6m5m/4/ I don't know php so can't tell if it's the problem, but it probably might be.

Comment: Are you sure it works fine in the fiddle? It doesn't here, unless I move the Javascript to the Javascript box... Oh, and it only opacitises the top image, no matter where you hover.

Comment: @AmitJoki The php only means that the images won't show up, it doesn't cause any extra problems.

Comment: @MrLister that's because the class isn't applied to other images

Comment: @MrLister If you apply the class `port-item-img` to other images, it too will be opacticized.

Comment: @MrLister thats exactly what I thought, and I know im enqueueing the script correctly in wordpress, I guess I will just use the css method. Im happy that all I did wrong was an extra ";"... pretty proud considering I learnt jQuery less than 24 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".port-item-img").hover(function() {
            $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
        }; // extra ;
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for those wondering.... is was a wordpress issue, wordpress doesn't allow `$(document).ready(){};`syntax instead you need to use `jQuery(document).ready($){};`